# How to use installed apps in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-apps

I've installed a Django app - `django_quiz` into my Django project. After some problems, everything seems to be ok (no errors) except the error in template. In the `django_quiz` installation is written, that you have to put `url(r'^q/', include('quiz.urls')),` into your `urls.py`.

Now, I've tried to go to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/q/` to see what happend but error is raised:

```
Exception Value:    
no such table: quiz_quiz
```

I didn't use third-party app yet so the solution may be obvious. What to do? How do I start to work with this quizes?

```
1   {% extends 'base.html' %}
2   {% load i18n %}
3   {% block title %}{% trans "All Quizzes" %}{% endblock %}
4   
5   {% block content %}
6   <h2>{% trans "List of quizzes" %}</h2>
7   

      {% if quiz_list %}



8           <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
9   
10            <thead>
11              <tr>
12                <th>{% trans "Title" %}</th>
13                <th>{% trans "Category" %}</th>
14                <th>{% trans "Exam" %}</th>
15                <th>{% trans "Single attempt" %}</th>
16                <th></th>
17              </tr>
```

Comment: Did you run the migrations?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I tried to makemigrations, but it said that No changes detected.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Thanks, I though that if makemigrations says no changes, I don't need to use migrate

Comment: No, because the migrations are supplied with the app; you don't need to make them, you need to apply them.

Answer (score -1):

If you have new Django >= 1.7, You need to make migrations like this:

```
1) ./manage.py makemigrations django_quiz (or maybe quiz)
2) ./manage.py migrate django_quiz
```

If you have Older Django

```
./manage.py schemamigration django_quiz
./manage.py mirgate djnago_quiz
```

First command will prepare migrations for database (commands to modify tables)
Second command will actually make changes to DB (create tables)